# Javascript having with arranging dynamic div boxes in javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

### First I've created a div with `id=mainC`, then through javascript I am trying to make 9 boxes and after every 3 boxes I want a line break and want to add numbering inside the boxes.

### |   1    |    2    |    3    |

### |   4    |    5    |    6    |

### |   7    |    8    |    9    |

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>JS</title>
</head>
<style>
#mainC{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    position: fixed;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -150px;
    margin-left: -150px;    
}
.inDiv{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px solid #000000;   
}
</style>
<body>
<div id="mainC">

</div>
</body>
<script>
var mainC = document.getElementById('mainC');
for(var i=1;i<=9;i++)
{
    var inDiv = document.createElement('div');
    inDiv.id = 'inDiv'+i;
    inDiv.className = 'inDiv';
    mainC.appendChild(inDiv);
    if (i%3 === 0)
    {
        document.getElementById('mainC').innerHTML = "<br>";    
    }
}
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can archive this using CSS:

https://jsfiddle.net/neyk2Le0/2/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>JS</title>
</head>
<style>
#mainC{
    width:306px;
    height:306px;
    position: fixed;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -150px;
    margin-left: -150px;    
}
.inDiv{
    width:100px;
    height:60px;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    background-color: #ccc;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 40px 0 0 0;
}
</style>
<body>
<div id="mainC">

</div>
</body>
<script>
var mainC = document.getElementById('mainC');
for(var i=1;i<=9;i++)
{
    var inDiv = document.createElement('DIV');
    inDiv.id = 'inDiv'+i;
    inDiv.className = 'inDiv';
    inDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i));
    mainC.appendChild(inDiv);

}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: i cant understand how are you having a line break after 3 boxes is it using padding of 40px top?

Comment: Using CSS, the wrapper div element is 306px; so when the first three div elements get rendered inside the wrapper, the total width of the three is (300*3)px + 6px (border width) = 306px. Now, the fourth div element will start in the new line automatically. The same will happen with the 7th and the 10th...

Comment: Padding 40px on top is to push the number to the middle of the box. Since there's 40px padding, I set height = 60px so total box's height is still 100px

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var mainC = document.getElementById('mainC');
for(var i=1;i<=9;i++)
{
    var inDiv = document.createElement('div');
    inDiv.id = 'inDiv'+i;
    inDiv.className = 'inDiv';
    inDiv.innerHTML = i;

    mainC.appendChild(inDiv);
}
```

CSS

```
#mainC{
  width:100px;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#mainC div{
  padding:10px;
  border-left: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom:5px;
}

#mainC div:nth-child(3n+0){
  border-right: 1px solid red;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u8bpan3m/